# Change fieldset class on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to change the class of a fieldset when ever a checkbox is clicked.

Here is what I have:

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=cbLimit.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        $("#fsLimit").removeClass(".active");
        $("#fsLimit").addCLass(".inactive");
    });
});
```

**css**

```
.active {
    border: 1px solid #3f90cb;
    padding: 10px;      
    margin: 10px;       
}    
.inactive {
    border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    padding: 10px;      
    margin: 10px;     
}
```

**asp**

```
<fieldset id="fsLimit" class="active" >
    <legend >
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbLimit" runat="server" /><asp:Label ID="lblLimit" runat="server" AssociatedControlId="cbLimit" text="Limit"/>
    </legend>
    <!--Some stuff-->
</fieldset>
```

Nothing happens. I tried to just put an alert inside the .click-function and that worked fine. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **change** event, and remove `.` from class name in addClass and removeClass method

```
$("#<%=cbLimit.ClientID%>").change(function () {
    $("#fsLimit").removeClass("active"); //Removed .
    $("#fsLimit").addCLass("inactive"); //Removed .
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick :D I'll accept your answer when I can (says 12 minutes).